# How one to many relationship looks like in crow's foot notation?

Tags: database-design, erd

I was designing a database model using **chen notation**, but there's one part where I'm not sure how it will looks like in **crow's foot notation**. As far as I know, a new relation needs to be created when the relationship between two entities is **many to many**, which looks something like this:

[image]              [image]

However, I'm creating a new relation for entities with **one to many** relationship as I'm adding attribute for the relationship. Therefore, I'm not really sure on how it will looks in crow's foot notation.

[image]

The primary key for book and publisher is just **bookID** and **publisher ID**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ER-diagram-symbols-and-meaning) you can read more about crows foot notation.

A simple diagram that shows the cardinality notation (taken from the link above):

[image: erd-notation]

And an example of a one-to-many relationship:

[image: one-to-many-book]

I think it is worth learn to draw diagrams using crows foot because it is what almost everybody uses.